# Redirect old domain to new domain using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Its really basic but I cant make it work. How can I redirect an old domain to a new domain, and also redirect certain pages from the old domain, to new urls from the new domain?

Redirect 1
http://www.oldsite.com
https://newsite.com/

Redirect 2
http://www.oldsite.com/about/
https://newsite.com/this/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.shion-kaikan.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://shion.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not match against URL scheme or path in `%{HTTP_HOST}` . You can only match against your domain name ie . example.com or www.example.com .

The following should work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.shion-kaikan.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://shion.com/ [R=301,L]
```